# Sql Server Triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

why we use INSERTED in every statement of trigger in sql? For Example:

```
select @q = inserted.qty from inserted
```

So what does this last 'inserted' mean?

Comment: Sadiq, can you post some of your code so we can see what you're referring to? No one is able to answer this for you without more context.

Comment: Not sure if you have heard, but there's this thing where you can search answers to simple questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=inserted+sql+server+trigger

Answer (score 0):

inserted represents the data inserted into database which invoked the trigger. 
like wise deleted and updated are other keywords

Comment: There is no `updated` pseudo table - in case of an `UPDATE` trigger, you have `deleted` filled with the old values (before the update), and `inserted` with the new values